# How can I manage promise and map objects?

Tags: reactjs, async-await, react-props

I am working on a project in which data in my database is something like this:

[image: [![first_part]1]]
[image: secondpart]

I'm not getting what wrong am I doing! here is my
**FetchList.js**

```
import { useState } from "react";


const FetchList = async()=>{

    const[data, setData] =  useState()
    const response = await fetch('https://__firebase__url__');
    
    if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error("Something went wrong");
      }
  
      let responseData = await response.json();
      const loadedHospitals = [];
      for (const key in responseData){
        loadedHospitals.push({
          key: responseData[key].key,
          Name: responseData[key].Name,
          Email: responseData[key].Email,
          Contact_no: responseData[key].Contact_no,
          img: responseData[key].img,
        });
      }
      setData(loadedHospitals);
      const hospitals = data.map(hospital => {
        console.log(hospital);
       });
return data;
}
export default  FetchList;
```

I want to pass the entire result in an array to **ListHospital.js** and then map it with Card component.

```
import Card from "../UI/Card";
import FetchList from "./FetchList";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const ListHospitals = () => {
    const [data, setData] = useState();

    useEffect(() => {
        FetchList().then(data => setData(data));
    }, []);
    
    return data.map((item)=><Card>{item}</Card>);
}

export default ListHospitals;
```

Error:

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')

Comment: What is the problem that you have?

Comment: TypeError: data.map is not a function
@emkarachchi

Comment: `useState({})` has an object not an array

Comment: Yes now the error is `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')
`

Comment: Think you need to return the data from `FetchList ` . Try adding `return loadedHospitals`

Comment: still the same error cannot read property

Comment: In `FetchList` I'm tring to console.out the output but it's not working :(

Comment: React state is asynchronous, so `data` won't be immediately set after you `setData(loadedHospitals);`. It doesn't seem like `FetchList` needs state at all, really. Just operate on your data and return it.

Comment: @samuei Can you post the answer , because I had tried that but it didn't worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to write  `const [data, setData] = useState();` as  `const [data, setData] = useState([]);` first. as fetch list is an async function so it will take some time to fetch your data hence it is giving you an error. You can only use map on arrays and during the initial render the data variable is `undefined`.

Comment: Hey @Mob_Abominator I had already tried `useState([ ])` , `useState({ })` and `useState()` as well but it didn't worked for me

Answer (score 0):

`Fetching` query at the higher level like `App.js` solved my problem.
Like :-

```
function App() {
  const [ data, setData ] = useState([]);

  const fetching = async () => {
    const response = await fetch("_____url___");
    const responseData = await response.json();
    let loadedItem = [];
    for (const key in responseData) {
        loadedItem.push(responseData[key]);
    }
    console.log(loadedItem);
}
fetching();
  return (
    <>
      <h1>Hey</h1>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```